# lxd version conflict

Tags: lxd, conjure-up

Just installed conjure-up and when I run it I get the following -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/snap/conjure-up/557/bin/conjure-up", line 11, in <module>    
load_entry_point('conjure-up==2.3a1', 'console_scripts', 'conjure-up')
File "/snap/conjure-up/557/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/conjureup/app.py", >line 257, in main    utils.lxd_version(),  
File "/snap/conjure-up/557/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/conjureup/utils.py", >line 269, in lxd_version    raise 
Exception("Could not determine LXD version.") Exception: Could not 
determine LXD version.
```

When I run `lxd --version`

```
2.0.10
```

The command that looks for the lxd version when running conjure up is

```
conjure-up.lxd --version
```

I get

```
2.14
```

Nothing in conjure-up.log or journalctl shows what the problem might be

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: The SNAP paths should be in your environment when running conjure-up. `$SNAP/lib` needs to be in `ld_library_path`.

Comment: I exported the LD paths to both lxd and conjure-up and ran ldconfig. Still not seeing each other

Comment: I've the same issue with conjure-up. we can't deploy Openstack Autopilot with that.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the core snap that caused classic snaps (like conjure-up) to fail when a new core snap is installed. This has since been fixed and available by running:

`sudo snap refresh core --stable`

You can read more about the issue here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-2-26-9-and-conjure-up-no-longer-work/1348

Answer (score 1):

Regarding  the issue

```
Exception("Could not determine LXD version.") Exception: Could not 
determine LXD version.
```

The script cannot determine the version of lxd. The reason is an error that is not reported,

```
 /snap/conjure-up/561/wrappers/lxd: 9: exec: aa-exec: not found
```

What I did to fix it was to add the `/usr/sbin` to the path, this fixed the problem.

Here's how I identified the issue and how I fixed it.

I had a user "stack" for openstack deployment, I observed that after running the command:

```
conjure-up.lxd --version
```

I received this error:

```
/snap/conjure-up/561/wrappers/lxd: 9: exec: aa-exec: not found
```

I view  the file

```
view /snap/conjure-up/561/wrappers/lxd
```

and found the line.

```
exec aa-exec -p unconfined -- "$0" "$@".
```

This `aa-exec` cannot be found.

If you run as root or a super user `which aa-exec` you can see the directory.

If you add `/usr/sbin` to the user path and rerun the command, the deployment starts.

The way to add a path to environment PATH:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin

Comment: I was getting the same error in my deployment. I tried also a lot of other alternatives like remove and install conjure or lxd, but not worked.